# /tmp/krb5cc not getting deleted on it's own

Tags: linux, caching, kerberos, host, tmp

An ftp id wasn't able to authenticate itself using kerberos because it wasn't able to create /tmp/krb5cc_[uid]. This was caused because /tmp ran out of inode space, as there were innumerbale (don't know the exact number as ls -l|wc -l fails as there are too many arguments) kerberos credential cache files. Some were older than 2 years. Why is that the credential cache is not getting deleted after use? Is this a problem with the user profile?

Thanks, Pratheeksha

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a problem with the user profile?

I came across this very old question and am astonished to see no answers.

According to `man kdestroy`, it is good practice to delete caches when you logout. You can do so by specifying the appropriate calls in `/etc/bash.bash_logout`.

This could contain the following: `kdestroy -q` or `rm /tmp/krb5cc_$(id -u)` to clean up the caches, note that `kdestroy` deletes the cache reagrdless of name so is safer.